# How to import a kotlin data class in Java class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a kotlin class **VouchersResponse.kt**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
    data class VouchersResponse (
        @SerializedName("genotp") val genotp : Genotp,
        @SerializedName("exp") val exp : Exp,
        @SerializedName("otpvalidate") val otpvalidate : Otpvalidate,
        @SerializedName("status") val status : Status
    )
```

In java class I am not able to import `VouchersResponse`

```
public class HomePageBannerRepository {
    private Observable<VouchersResponse> movieDBResponseObservable;
}
```

**What I am able to do:** I am able to import  kotlin data class in another kotlin class

**Question**: How to import a `kotlin` data class in java class

Comment: what's the package name for `VouchersResponse`?

Comment: @sonnet .... `package com.spurtree.demo.models.ResponseObjects`
 .... that was the issue ... after adding package import it resolved ... Post it as answer ... i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the class using the package name:

```
import com.my.package.MyClass
```